# Factors that facilitate to compare two algorithms of the same time complexity

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have to complete a study on analysis of digital algorithms. I need some expert ideas on the topic.
I understand that two algorithms having the same time complexity are affected by the constant, say alpha, in there complexity equations. The algorithm with a greater value of alpha is considered poorer to an algorithm with a smaller alpha.
An example equation for the complexity would be
F(n)=A(n^2+2n)

What other factors govern the comparison between two algorithms in case they are of the same time complexity? Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is another factor to consider, for example Mergesort typically runs in the same time complexity (albeit with a lower constant factor) but in twice the space as Heapsort (I say "typically" because an in-place Mergesort is usually O(n^2)).  A basic algorithm to compute the prime numbers up to N requires that you store all of the primes up to N, whereas the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is more time-efficient but requires that you store all of the numbers (not all of the primes) up to N.  [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) runs in O(n) (as opposed to Heapsort/Mergesort/Quicksort which run in O(n*log(n))), but hardly anybody uses Radix Sort because it requires much more memory and has poor cache performance.  Also note that a recursive algorithm typically requires more space (in the form of the stack) than an equivalent iterative algorithm.

Average time complexity is another factor - Bubblesort and Quicksort run in the same worst case time complexity (O(n^2)), but Bubblesort's average time complexity is n^2 while Quicksort's average time complexity is n*log(n).  Insertion and lookup in a balanced binary tree has a worst and average time of n*log(n), while insertion and lookup in a hash table usually has a worst time of O(n) and constant average time.

Sometimes algorithms will have the same time complexity, but one will use less-expensive operations.  For example, the standard algorithm for matrix multiplication is O(n^3); an alternative algorithm (whose name I forget) runs in the same time complexity, but it users fewer multiplications and more additions (additions are less expensive than multiplications).  (In this case the constant factors are affected so it's still an apples to apples comparison, but beware algorithm comparisons that are apples to oranges.)

Another consideration is parallelization.  A basic matrix multiplication algorithm runs in the same time complexity as a [block matrix multiplication algorith](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix), but the latter is much more efficient than the former when run in parallel.  A subset of parallel algorithms also have the property that they are "lock-free," meaning that they achieve synchronization without the use of semaphores or monitors or other locking structures; a subset of lock-free algorithms are "wait-free," meaning that all threads are guaranteed to make progress.

Cache performance is another consideration - the basic and block matrix multiplication algorithms use roughly the same amount of memory, but the block algorithm has better cache behavior (fewer cache misses)

Stability is a factor in many numerical algorithms.  When solving ordinary differential equations, the fourth order Runge-Kutta method converges much faster than the implicit Euler method, but the implicit Euler method will always converge to the solution whereas the Runge-Kutta method may exhibit instability (e.g. converging to Infinity or NAN).

Many algorithms require that all data reside in main memory; in contrast, an external algorithm only requires that a portion of the data reside in main memory at any given time.  For example, a classic Mergesort algorithm requires that all elements being sorted reside in memory, while a Polyphase Mergesort only requires that a subset of the elements reside in memory while the rest reside on a hard drive or across a network.